# Forced Redirect only in Chrome Browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, joomla

I have a Javascript/redirect issue that only occurs in Chrome. If you set your default language to Spanish in your browser, and visit this page:

http://www.fastrackids.com/es/bogota

in every browser but Chrome it works fine. In Chrome, you are redirected after about 3 seconds to the calendar page. (Calendar is one of the tabs on the page.)

This only happens when Chrome is set to the Spanish default language. And it does not happen in any other browser. I am not a developer, but I have narrowed it down to a script. If I delete the script, no issue, but if I leave it in, it affects Chrome. The script is as follows (the URL that chrome redirects to is in the script):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() 
{

    function loadCal(link)
    {
        jQuery('#loading_page').show();
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: link,
            cache: false,
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(data) {
                jQuery("#listings_calendar").html(data);
                jQuery('#loading_page').hide();
            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                jQuery("#listings_calendar").html('<h2>There was an error retrieving the calendar.</h2>');
                jQuery('#loading_page').hide();
            }
        });
    };  


    var date = new Date();
    var date_str = date.getFullYear() + '-' + (date.getMonth()+1) + '-' + date.getDate();

    var link = '/index.php?option=com_jumi&fileid=5&Itemid=49&task=ShowCView&format=raw&SearchDate=' + date_str + '&listing_id=' + jQuery('#listing_id').val();
    loadCal(link);


    jQuery('#listings_calendar').delegate("a", "click", function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        loadCal(jQuery(this).attr('href') + '&format=raw');
        return false;
    });

});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I am not a developer.

Comment: I tried to reproduce but FF and Chrome have the same behavior with Spanish language. It never goes to the calendar for me. I could be doing the test wrong but I think I've tried what you outlined. You are absolutely sure it is a Chrome issue? You have cleared the entire cache and still can reproduce?

Comment: Yes, cleared the cache, etc. Several people have replicated it in Chrome. If you change default browser language to Spanish, then go back to that page, reload, it shows it for a few seconds, then reloads it. Only in Chrome, and we are on the latest version. It works fine in all other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Luckily ,I can reproduce it.
I traced your code and found something.

It's begin at `templates/jreviews_overrides/views/themes/ftk/theme_js/listings.js` in the function loadCal which make Ajax call to

```
http://www.fastrackids.com/index.php?option=com_jumi&fileid=5&Itemid=49&task=ShowCView&format=raw&SearchDate=2013-7-10&listing_id=453&_=1373450843892
```

In English it's return Calendar table as expected. but in Spanish it return this code

```
<html><head><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;http://www.fastrackids.com/showprofile?SearchDate=2013-7-10&_=1373450843892&format=raw&lang=es&listing_id=453&ss=&task=ShowCView" /></head><body></body></html>
```

As you can see, It's try to redirect to another url which contains Calendar.

I believe that's redirection by `meta tag` are designed to redirect the webpage not Ajax call.

If you want to redirect an Ajax call. better use `header` redirect.

in PHP you can do:

```
header('Location: http://somewhere.com/blah')
```